# count select option in protractor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, protractor, html-select

I want to count the number of element in an select option, but it doesn't work.
This is the HTML code of the website :

```
<select class="kdninputtextrequired" id="OBJ_90200782_0" name="OBJ_90200782_0" size="1">
   <option value="">(Sélectionnez un élément)</option>
   <option value="0">Monsieur</option>
   <option value="1">Madame</option>
   <option value="2">Mademoiselle</option>
</select>
```

i tried to do this :

```
var nb = browser.element.all(by.id('OBJ_90200782_0')).count();
expect(nb).toBe(4);
```

but i have this message : "Expected 1 to be 4."

Why ? please help...

Answer (score 1):

you are counting the select element, try this instead:

```
browser.element(by.id('OBJ_90200782_0')).all(by.tagName('option').count();
```